# Is there any option to give discounts on products, based on ratios

Tags: magento-1.7

My current site is on jewellery. I want to give discounts based on diamond and metal weight's ratio.

Ex -
1 : 0.25   - Discount 25%
1 : 0.20   - Discount 20%

In admin is there any option or I will have to customize?